# PHP5 unable to get session of manager id and count 'not seen' in the forwarded column from report table

Tags: mysql

The problem is unable to get the session manager id and counting 'Not seen' in the forwarded field of report table which are equals to cidmid.
"Notice: Undefined index: cidmid in C:\xampp\htdocs\AAP\ci.php on line 58
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(forwarded) WHERE forwarded='Not seen'' at line 1"

```
<ul>    
<li><a href="viewreport.php">View Reports 
<?php 
$cidmID =$_SESSION['cidmid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM  report WHERE cidmid='$cidmID' AND 
forwarded,COUNT(forwarded) WHERE forwarded='Not seen'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "[".$row['COUNT(forwarded)']."]";
}?> </a> </li>
<ul>
```

I expect the the number of not seen reports by the session cidmid.

Comment: Your SQL syntax seems incorrect

Comment: That's why I am here!

Comment: how can I count 'not seen' by cidmid?

Comment: @Jorge  query needs to be:- `$query = "SELECT forwarded,COUNT(forwarded) FROM  report WHERE cidmid='$cidmID' AND forwarded='Not seen'";`. try and let us  know worked or not?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as well as removed library now. quickly move towards `PHP7` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library. As well as use `prepared statements` of these libraries to prevent your code from **_SQL INJECTION_** . As your current code is wide open for SQL injection.